# Где найти очень старый код?

Tags: javascript, python, java, любой-язык

Хочу посмотреть, как писали код "доисторические" разработчики - чисто интересно. Где можно найти примеры кода на языках **JavaScript**/Java/Python/C++... примерно через 0-30 лет от их первого выпуска? Меня никто не остановит, мне всё равно интересно

Comment: поисковик находится по другому адресу.

Comment: Поищите, например, исходники первого Doom, кажется их выкладывали. Там C++ )

Comment: @strawdog тогда по какому запросу искать?

Answer (score 7):

На вот [код](https://github.com/chrislgarry/Apollo-11) с Апполона-11, развлекайся: